Problems with OriginExt and PyOrigin
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm encountering an issue while trying to import PyOrigin and OriginExt modules in my Python environment. I'm using these modules to work with data analysis and visualization in OriginLab.
Here's the error message I'm getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Edu\PycharmProjects\ori\te.py", line 1, in 
import OriginExt
File "C:\Users\Edu\PycharmProjects\ori.venv\lib\site-packages\OriginExt_init_.py", line 1, in 
from .OriginExt import *
File "C:\Users\Edu\PycharmProjects\ori.venv\lib\site-packages\OriginExt\OriginExt.py", line 13, in 
from . import _OriginExt
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _OriginExt: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
It seems like the problem arises from not being able to find the _OriginExt module. I've tried reinstalling both PyOrigin and OriginExt packages, but the issue persists.
Python 3.10.11
I'm using Python 3.10.11 and OriginLab 2024. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I'm attempting to reinstall the libraries, but the error persists, indicating that the issue persists despite my efforts to rectify it.

Hi, have you tried following this hint from the Origin website:
If you are using an earlier version of Origin, you might see a MS DLL error at Origin startup, such as the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'originext'". In this case, we suggest you to download and install the MS redistributable package. The needed MS redistributable packages are listed in this web page, you can download the suitable package(s) according to the version of Origin you are using.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
